# Get custom attribute value of check box in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I need value of "compid" custom attribute in classic asp?

Below is the `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="238774" compid="1367" id="1" />
```

Thanks

Comment: do you work with code-behind? if yes show us, and what have you tried?

Comment: classic ASP doesn't have code-behind

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with classic ASP, as the form will only post the name and value fields, but if you were to do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="238774|1367" id="1" />
```

Then in your code use code like

```
<%

both_vals = Request("chk")

value = Split(both_vals)(0)
compid = Split(both_vals)(1)


%>
```

you then have both your values in variables that you can use from there,

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answer you can also use hidden fields.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="238774" id="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="compid-238774" value="1367" />
```

Considering `iCheckValue` variable is the value of selected checkbox's, you can then retrieve the `compid` value like this:

```
iCompID = Request( "compid-" & iCheckValue )
```